# How to display many plots together in the same output -python

Tags: python

[shot from Jupyter][1]

I am trying to display two plots output from function to be together in the same output.

Can anyone help?
thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABXMj.png

Comment: I think you are looking for subplots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `plt.subplots()` or else you can do the one as shown in the picture too by coding all the plots together and then giving `plt.show()` at last.

Answer (score 0):

Below each plot code use plt.plot():

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

plt.plot(ax=axes[0])
plt.plot(ax=axes[1])
```